# Download CSV from python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a set of data using pandas. I have been able to get an output and stored in a Data Frame(.to_csv). How do i download or export the csv file. I use Jupiter notebook.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, [please see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of what you need.

```py
df.to_excel("new.xlsx", sheet_name="stocks", index=False, startrow=2, startcol=1)
```

Here is an other example

```py
df_stocks = pd.DataFrame({
    'tickers': ['GOOGL', 'WMT', 'MSFT'],
    'price': [845, 65, 64 ],
    'pe': [30.37, 14.26, 30.97],
    'eps': [27.82, 4.61, 2.12]
})

df_weather =  pd.DataFrame({
    'day': ['1/1/2017','1/2/2017','1/3/2017'],
    'temperature': [32,35,28],
    'event': ['Rain', 'Sunny', 'Snow']
})


with pd.ExcelWriter('stocks_weather.xlsx') as writer:
    df_stocks.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="stocks")
    df_weather.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="weather")
```